# React Link component lose css or magin align when used

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a header in which I use css grid, in one of the areas I find 2 buttons which center using 'display: grid' in the parent and 'margin: auto' in the child. The buttons are centered correctly are 2 buttons, but if I want to add the Link component and put the button inside, it no longer looks centered but loses its alignment of the css but maintains all its styles of the original button, it is as if it lost the margin.

It should be vertically aligned, but if i use Link component it aligns to top.

Tried to add margin to the link component but can't fix it.

```
    <div className="loginArea">
      <button type="button" className="botonComun">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserPlus} /> Registro
      </button>
      <Link to="/login">
      <button type="button" className="botonComun">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignInAlt} /> Entrar
      </button>
      </Link>
    </div>


  .loginArea {
    grid-area: loginArea;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
    grid-gap: 12px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
}

Link {
  margin: auto;
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
}

.botonComun {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: $purpura;
  margin: auto;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-family: $fuenteprimaria;
  color: $blanco;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    background-color: $azul;
  }
}
```

**FIX**

I forgot the button and just stylize the Link component with the button class

Answer (score 0):

use onClick to call a function which would do the work of Link component.

```
const handleClick = () => {
  props.history.push('/route');
}
return(
...
<li onClick={handleClick}>mylink</li>
...
 )
```